What do you do if the numerical values of the spatial Durbin model LM test (spatdiag) are too large to display accurate data?
Please help me, I am using Stata for LM test and the code is as follows：
spatdiag,weights(x1)
however, the Lagrange multiplier and Robust Lagrange multiplier are displayed in scientific notation due to their large numerical values, and I cannot see the accurate data. Is there any way to solve this? I would like to obtain the results of the corresponding indicators with 3 decimal places.
I have tried using outreg2, estout, etc. However, regression results, instead of LM test, is output. I also tried local r(list), still no results.

Something is wrong here beyond your question. Moran I is never as big as that.
